# Conditional Formatting - highlight "Top 3" - Problem with duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a set of data (numbers) in one column. What I wanted to achieve is to highlight (directly in this column) top 3 values. It works fine  if there are no duplicates but if there are any, I got wrong result (duplicates are considered as unique values).

I wrote a simple function (please see it below), however it doesn't work as well.

```vb
Function isTop(cellTop As Range, rngTop As Range, noTop As Integer) As Boolean

'cellTop - cell to be checked
'rngTop - range to be considered
'noTop - nth top value

Dim iStartTop As Integer, noOccurTop As Integer, noTopUpdate As Integer

    For iStartTop = 1 To noTop

        If cellTop.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rngTop, iStartTop) Then
            isTop = True
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next iStartTop

End Function
```

Let's assume that there is the following set of data (12 elements) available in column A:

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

and I want to highlight top 3 elements (by using conditional formatting and either standard top 3 condition or function =isTop(A1,A:A,3)). After applying any of provided methods, only cells containing "4" will be highlighted.

However, I expect to have "4", "3" and "2" highlighted. Is there a way to solve this problem if duplicates are present in a given column?

Thank you in advance for your help.
Best Regards,
Kamil

Comment: And do you expect all values with 4, 3 and 2 to be highlighted? Or just the first 4, 3 and 2?

Comment: yes, all values should be highlighted (3 x "4", 3 x "3" and 3 x "2") and that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So here is one way to do what you want:

Create three new conditional formatting rules:

1. Apply to range `$A:$A`

   ```
   =$A1=MAX($A$1:$A$12)
   ```
2. Apply to range `$A:$A`

   ```
   =$A1=LARGE(($A$1:$A$12<MAX($A$1:$A$12))*($A$1:$A$12),1)
   ```
3. Apply to range `$A:$A`

   ```
   =$A1=LARGE(($A$1:$A$12<LARGE(($A$1:$A$12<MAX($A$1:$A$12))*($A$1:$A$12),1))*($A$1:$A$12),1)
   ```

[image]

You can also go the VBA route but that's up to you.

Comment: Wow. Thank you a lot for quick answer and great idea. I can’t wait to test it. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, let me know how it goes

Comment: It works great! Thank you. I have one more question: is there a way to do it more dynamic? When the number of top values is determined based on the number of rows?  In my case there is a threshold (sometimes there are top 3 or 5 or 10 to be highlighted). Is there a way to pass it as argument in function? If there are no duplicates, “LARGE” function works perfectly but if there are any, the list of highlighted cells is not complete. I was thinking about an array in VBA to store unique (top) values and then in a loop I would check the entire range but maybe there is more sophisticated way?

Comment: @Cammil, I'm not sure it's possible using dynamic ranges AND dynamic number of top values through conditional formatting. If you decide to go VBA route, fille a background is not the same as applying a conditional formatting to a cell. Just be aware of that and I'm sure it won't be too hard. In this case VBA might be just elegant enough :)

Comment: Thank you again for quick answer. Well, this is what I was afraid of. So, I need to drop the idea of using conditional formatting. Let me try with VBA then. Nevertheless, “the trick” with 3 formulas you provided I will use in the future for sure. Thanks again 

Comment: If you can use on more column it can become very easy without vba, but that's up to you! @Cammil

Comment: Well, I wish I could. Unfortunately, I cannot modify the worksheet (columns are fixed). So, the only way is to create a macro but thank you anyway.